# CSV file to array with entry validation in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, csv, import

I tried to convert an csv file to an array with str_getcsv in php. Afterwards I want to check if the form submit is in the csv file alreaddy.

My code:

```
//get form input
$email = $_POST["email"]; 

//create array
$csv = array('str_getcsv', file('file.csv')); 

//functio to check csv content for $email
function val() {
   if (in_array($email, $csv)) {
     echo "Enthalten";
   } 
   else {
     echo "Nicht enthalten";
   }
}
```

The check is working now. But the code inside of the else {} statement ist   not.

```
<?php
$email = $_POST["email"];
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv'));

foreach ($csv as $row) {
if (in_array($email, $row)) {

    echo "Error";

} else {

    // this code is working fine if seperated
    $list = array (array($email),);
    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a');
    foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    fclose($fp);


// here is a working skript to send an email to the $email recipient


}
}


?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `array()` be `array_map()`? Is that in the real script or a copying error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv'))` will return a multi-dimensional array. `in_array()` isn't going to work like this.

You'll need to iterate over each row in the CSV to look for the email.

```
//get form input
$email = $_POST["email"]; 

//create array
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv'));

foreach ($csv as $row) {
    if (in_array($email, $row)) {
        echo "Enthalten";
    } else {
        echo "Nicht enthalten";
    }
}
```

Comment: `str_getcsv()` returns a 1-dimensional array. But when you use `array_map()`, you combine all those arrays into a 2-d array.

Comment: ah, yes...that's more clear. I guess what I meant was '$csv is going to be a multi-dimensional array and will have to be evaluated as such'

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. May I ask you to read the edit I created?

Comment: This is starting to feel like I'm writing your script for you. Looks like you're trying to add the email address to the csv file if it's not there?

Comment: I don't want you to feel like that. I'm sorry. The script works perfectly if it's not inside the else statement. I just can't figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. first convert your csv file into array.

   `$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv'));`
2. secondly, use `array_search` for the email inside the array above. (e.g: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

   `$key = array_search($email, $csv);`
3. if email exist, it will return you the key inside the array.

Comment: I dont't need this in my case. I just need to verify if the email is there or not.